# Environment Variables in PATH Not Expanded for non-Admin Command Prompt?

Tags: windows-7, path, environment-variables, command-line-interface

I have a Windows 7 machine which, when Command Prompt is run by a normal user, fails to expand environment variables in the `%PATH%`. If command prompt is instead run as administrator (right click, *Run as administrator*) then `%PATH%` is appropriately expanded.

Specifically, `%PATH%` for `cmd.exe` run as the user (displayed via `set path`) is as follows:

```
Path=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\
```

...whereas `%PATH%` for `cmd.exe` run as Administrator is as follows:

```
Path=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\
```

I tried logging in as a new user to create a new profile, and the issue persists on that profile as well. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\PATH` does not exist, and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path` matches the defined system-wide path in Computer Properties -> Environment Variables.

Does anyone have any ideas of what this might be, or where I can look?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two things I might try.

1. Run an `sfc /scannow` to see if that fixes any larger issues at play.
2. Check the registry for the `Path` key in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`. What's the *type*. It should say **`REG_EXPAND_SZ`**

Comment: That was it. If I take a normal machine and set it to **`REG_SZ`** the problem occurs, if I set it back to **`REG_EXPAND_SZ`** it gets fixed.

Comment: @Steve - Sweet! I even learned something about that :)

Comment: But I wonder. Why it creates those env vars with the wrong value type in the registry? I don't remember having this problem before, I'm using Windows 8.1 Update 1 and it seems this issue might have happen even in XP! http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329308

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem - the simple solution was to add **a semi-colon after the alias in the path definition**.

### Long story:

I'm using `node.js` so have a *NODE_HOME* alias defined via a user environment variable. I then append this alias to my *PATH* environment variable.

What I find is that after a re-boot, the shell has lost the path to *NODE_HOME* so `npm` etc. won't work. What's going on?

On inspection, I see that *NODE_HOME* is set, but that it has magically acquired a semi-colon.

```
C:\Users\ob>echo %NODE_HOME%
C:\Users\ob\node-8.11.1;
```

*PATH* now ends in the literal string *%NODE_HOME%* instead of the expanded path to the node folder:

```
C:\Users\ob>echo %PATH%
C:\Program...rams\Git\cmd;%NODE_HOME%
```

To fix it:

First, delete the errant semi-colon from the end of the definition of *NODE_HOME*.

Second, *add* a semi-colon after the *NODE_HOME* symbol in the definition of *PATH*:

```
C:\Program...rams\Git\cmd;%NODE_HOME%;
```

Now when I start a new shell and expand *PATH*, it finds *NODE_HOME*:

```
C:\Users\ob>echo %PATH%
C:\Program...ams\Git\cmd;C:\Users\tkobo\Installations\node-8.11.1;
```

And `npm` works again!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue while trying to configure Maven...

I found this [post on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/236167/how-do-i-append-user-defined-environment-variables-to-the-system-variable-path-in) that shed some light on the issue, but it didn't work for me. The issue seemed to be about rights elevation, since an admin shell would work, but a user shell wouldn't. I finally decided to just recreate the user variables as system variables instead, and add those to the global path.

This worked for a couple of variables, but I had one pair that still wouldn't expand. I recreated them with new names a couple of times, to no avail. However, the variables finally expanded correctly in the user shell after I disabled UAC, rebooted, re-enabled UAC, and rebooted again.

Answer (score -2):

**PROBLEM**:
My issue was only sinilar, as I understand you correctly. My "Path" contained ...;%ANT_HOME%\bin;...
I had teh variable ANT_HOME correctly set under System (not user) Variables, and CMD --> SET same as "echo %ANT_HOME%" printed it correctly.

**SOLUTION**:
I solved the problem by **moving the folder** from c:\dev\3rd\ant... **to** c:**Programm Files (x86)**\dev\3rd\ant...