# Adding .CMD Files to Path in System Environment Variables settings?

Tags: windows-server-2008, environment-variables

I would like to run a bunch of .CMD files from anywhere on my server. 
However, when I add the path that these files are in to my PATH in 
System Environment Variables, they don't run. I can run them if I 
go to the actual folder, however.

I am trying to make the following directory globally accessible:

> C:\Amazon\IAMCli-1.5.0\bin\

AWS_IAM_HOME is set to:

> C:\Amazon\IAMCli-1.5.0

My PATHEXT profile is as such:

> .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

If I run my Path command, I get the following reply:

> PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN
>   Card;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth
>   Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data
>   Protection\Access\Advanced\Wave\Gemalto\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;C:\Program
>   Files\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\OpenSSL\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
>   Installer\;C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
>   Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows
>   Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\; C:\Amazon\IAMCli-1.5.0\bin\;
>   C:\Amazon\ElasticLoadBalancing-1.0.17.0\bin\;
>   C:\Amazon\AutoScaling-1.0.61.1\bin\; C:\OpenSSL\bin\;

I am trying to run the following .CMD file globally by issuing

> C:\Amazon\IAMCli-1.5.0\bin\iam-userlistbypath.cmd

I am logged in as a non-admin user by have verified that if I run the Command 
prompt as admin, I get the same result. The permissions for the folder

> C:\Amazon\IAMCli-1.5.0

are:

```
Authenticated Users (Modify, Read & Execute, List folder contents, Read, Write) 
SYSTEM (Full control) 
Administrators (Full control) 
Users (Read & Execute, List folder contents, Read)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Add some details about what you actually have done.  What is the actual path to the files?  If you do an `echo %PATH%` in your terminal do you see the path you expect including that directory?

Comment: Hi Zoredache, details provided. Please let me know if I have missed anything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you test this with as short a path as possible, such as %systemroot%\system32;and the path of one of your applications?

Answer (score 1):

I see spaces on the C:\Amazon entries.  Try removing those first.  If it's comma-delimited, the spaces might change the PATH from "C:\Amazon..." to " C:\Amazon..." which can be entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

You state that you're logged in as non-admin.  The issue sounds similar to this question:

[Environment Variables in PATH Not Expanded for non-Admin Command Prompt?](https://serverfault.com/questions/300544/environment-variables-in-path-not-expanded-for-non-admin-command-prompt?rq=1)

Comment: Hi George. I was wondering if it was a permissions issue also. However, when I log into my CMD prompt as Admin, i still have the same problem. If I run my command at C:\, it says the command is not recognized. However, if I run the same command at C:\Amazon\IAMCli-1.5.0\bin, it runs. It doesn't seem to matter if I am admin or not.

Comment: OK what do you get when you type:

    `Echo %PATH% path.txt | 
    find "C:\Amazon\IAMCli-1.5.0\bin" path.txt`  (trying to ensure there's no typos in the PATH variable)

?

Comment: I'll ask the obvious here, you've stored your CMD files _as well as the programs they call_ in the bin folder, yes?  I know... of course you did.  Just thinking that if either the CMD's or the stuff they use aren't in the path you'd see what you're seeing.  I did a little test on my 2008 r2 server, created a new folder off the root, added that folder to the path, and wrote a two line test.cmd to that folder ("@echo off" and then "echo testing!").  The test executed from outside the folder.

Comment: Well, it is a straight download from AWS. I haven't moved anything from the BIN folder. So, each and every CMD file has an associated file by a similar name.

Comment: OK.  can you invoke those files from your command prompt? Say, by typing `program-name /?`

Comment: Yes, absolutely. But, as stated above, only in the containing folder.

Comment: This might be of some help.  [link]http://serverfault.com/questions/300544/environment-variables-in-path-not-expanded-for-non-admin-command-prompt

Comment: OK, thanks again George. The scan is running now - I'll let you know if that helps. Thanks much.